# Adding a branch code to my swift code, is there a difference?

Tags: banking, international, international-transfer, wire-transfer, swift

I have been receiving money from Romania to Indonesia using the swift code CENAIDJA for the past two months. This month there was an error in the swift code but when the sender added 'XXX' making it CENAIDJAXXX, the process went through.

I asked the receiving bank and they said they usually only use CENAIDJA without the branch code, does this mean the money that has been sent is lost or will be returned back to the sender's account?

Comment: is there only one branch of your bank in Indonesia, or do you have some other reason to believe a branch code is not needed?

Comment: Who told the sender to add `XXX`?